# How to get text from a web page - document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to get some text from the website.

I tried this, but it doesn't work, it gives me "undefined"

```
CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("var elems1 = document.getElementsByClassName('some-text')");
            CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("for(var i = 0; i < elems1.length; i++){var textt = elems1[i].innerText}");
            CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("alert(textt)");
```

and this is what I am trying to target

```
<p class="some-text">
        hello World
    </p>
```

Comment: what page are you trying to get the data from and what data are you trying to get?

Comment: @IvanD I rather won't tell, cause it's for my job and I really don't want to expose it, and even if I do, you can't access this content because you need to log in using your company's account. i just need it for this element "<p class="some-text">
        hello World
    </p>"

Comment: as @IvanD answered, it was literally your code and it works. You may have typos in your code. Double check.

Comment: I double checked and I found an issue, I was missing a letter "s" in "some-texts" lol, thank you very much guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('some-text');

for (const element of elements) {
  console.log(element.innerText);
}
```

```html
<p class="some-text">
  Text from paragraph 1
</p>

<p class="some-text">
  Text from paragraph 2
</p>
```